# What does the - mean on a Rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^(dir1|file1) - [L]
```

If this rule IS THE CASE then other rewrite rules should NOT apply.

Since we are on a .htaccess context, having only the [L] will be useless.

So, we need two things:

To have the - sign.

To have this rule before all other RewriteRules on our .htaccess file.

**If all above assumptions are correct and precise**, I would like to ask:

*What does the `-` mean, and what does it do on this context?*

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rhs) have this info:

> **- (dash)**
>
> A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

Comment: @Dave thanks. I still not conecting the dots. Why will that enable the real [L] usage on a .htaccess context ? In other words, why will that dash do something that, the [l] alone could do. The manual explanation is not clear to me, since I'm not a proficient English reader. :(

Comment: The rewrite rule defines a way for the server to alter URLs. When it matches a URL with the pattern, (`^(dir1|file1)`), it then looks to the next part of the rule to see how it should change the URL. The `-` just tells the server not to change the URL. The `[L]` (for "Last") then tells the server not to process any more rules.

Comment: @Dave Child: Hmm... I guess I'm reading to much perhaps... `RewriteEngine on rewriteRule a b [L] rewriteRule b c` "Most people would think that when requesting /a, the internally requested file would be /b because of the [L] flag. Well, it's not. The last requested file will actually be /c. To understand why, you need to understand how mod_rewrite handles a request in a per-directory context." source: http://www.colder.ch/news/01-26-2007/24/truth-about-the-last-mod_.html

Comment: @Dave Child: So... please confirm if my assumption is correct: the rule will be applied to /c because, since there is no dash `-` sign, we will stay with b path, because it will be untouched by the preceding (same as after?) rule? Is that it ? (if not, please take a deep breath. :D)

Comment: I don't know, I'm afraid. I've always taken the [L] flag to finish processing of rules. I'm reading the docs now, but things are not becoming a great deal clearer as yet!

Comment: Related to this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276668/the-dash-on-htaccess-the-remaining-question